# Can i use both Google Analytics and Google Ads Tag for tracking same event in Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads, google-tag-manager

I am not very experienced with Google Tag Manager, I wanted to track users who are filling a specific form on my website. So i have set up Google Analytics: Universal Analytics Tag for tracking users who are directly going to website and submitting the form (this tag seems to be working fine and getting fired) but the other Google Adwords Conversion Tracking Tag, which is also created to track the same action is not getting fired. Since it's the same action I am trying to track, both the tags have same click IDs in Google Tag Manager.

Why is only the Google Analytics tag for the same action getting fired?

Comment: Are you using a form submit trigger or a click element trigger?